# How can I convert a true type font to a vector font

Tags: fonts

I need to use the dynamic font functionality in GDscript and for that it needs a vector font. It only needs to simple and clear so I put an outline around the characters.

How can I convert one of the many easy to read true types- could be Arial- to a vector font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenType / TrueType fonts typically have vector outlines. There is a different sense of "vector font" (also called "stroke font") typically used on plotters, but that doesn't appear to be what is meant by "vector font" in the context of DynamicFont for GDscript:

> DynamicFont renders vector font files (such as TTF or OTF) dynamically at runtime instead of using a prerendered texture atlas like BitmapFont.

From https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_dynamic.font.html